# CSS is not applying to div with Gridview

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I want to have a div with my Gridview in it but the CSS for my div is not working. Here is the code:

```
<div class="grid">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="grid" CellPadding="1">
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

And my CSS is like:

```
.grid{

float:right;
border:solid;
margin: 2px;
width:400px;
}
```

And the generated HTML :

```
<div class="grid">
<div>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="grid" CellPadding="1">
</asp:GridView>
</div>
</div>
```

Even The border is not displayed.I don't know where that other div comes from but when I apply the style on the second div in Firebug it works.

Comment: hi now try to this way for border border:solid 2px red;

Comment: did your `css` is loading in your `html` file like in the `link` tag

Comment: how weird, no it is not loading but it is in the same sheet as the others and the other ones apply!

Comment: What exactly do you want, as you've given same class to the parent `<div>` as well as the `GridView` ? to which you want to target ?

Comment: Hi What exactly you want?

Comment: I want to apply my css to my div but didn't work, then tried the gridview also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

HI now used to border property 
as like this

```
.grid{
border:solid 2px red;
}
```

or you can try to this way

```
.grid{
border-style: solid;
}
```

> The border CSS property is a shorthand property for setting the
>   individual border property values in a single place in the style
>   sheet. border can be used to set the values for one or more of:
>   border-width, border-style, border-color.

More about **[click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)**

Border style **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

Just correct your css like

**CSS**

```
.grid { 
 float:right;
 border: 2px solid green;
 margin: 2px;
 width:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using ASP, you'll have to use a special syntax to apply the css.

```
BorderWidth="1px" BackColor="#000000"
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx for more.

Answer (score 0):

```
.grid{
overflow:hidden;
float:right;
border:solid;
margin: 2px;
width:400px;
}
```

I have added overflow:hidden which I believe should solve your problem.